# Cannot run MSTest in FAKE build script

Tags: mstest, f#-fake

I have a FAKE script that is attempting to run MSTest.
I am getting a 'Not Defined' error on MSTest.
From what I can gather in the documentation the MSTest helper should be in FakeLib.dll and in the 'Fake' namespace.  Is that wrong?

Why would I be getting this error?

```
#I "packages/FAKE/tools"
#r "packages/FAKE/tools/FakeLib.dll"
open Fake

...  many build steps working fine

Target "UnitTest" (fun _ ->
    trace "Run Unit Tests..."
    !! (testDir @@ "*.Tests.dll")
      |> MSTest (fun p -> { p })
    ()
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to include the `open Fake.MSTest`. Below is the snippet I use for unit tests.

```
open Fake.MSTest

Target "UnitTests" (fun _ ->
    let msTestParams p =
        { p with
            ResultsDir = resultsDir
            WorkingDir = testOutDir
            TestSettingsPath = sd @@ "Local.testsettings"
            ErrorLevel = ErrorLevel.Error
            NoIsolation = false }

    !! (testOutDir + @"\*.Tests.dll")
    |> MSTest msTestParams
)
```